# Resize the width of the <li> to fit <ul> using inline

Tags: html, css

I want to make the li auto resize the width to make it perfectly fit on the ul regardless the screen size.

Here is the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/y3bjokwx/

CSS:

```
ul {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

li{
  display: inline-block;
  width:60px;
  height:60px; 
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
     <li > <!-- over 1000 images -->
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
</ul>
```

Below image is not something I want, as there is still have space between the images and scrollbar
[image: Not fit]

Below image is what I want to achieve. It will automatically resize the width to fit the width of the ul regardless of the screen size.

[image: Fit]

Comment: try `img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}`

Comment: @roottraveller not working. tested on jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a flexible CSS grid.

```css
ul {
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 8px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    height:60px;
    
}

img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
     <li >
              <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
     </li>
</ul>
```

With these changes you will automatically fit the pictures in a row and scale them above 60px width if there is enaugh space.

Comment: sound promising, testing on my real application now

Comment: @Rick keep in mind that the images get strechted a bit horizontally because of the "minmax" function used. Also if you want to have a look at the "magic" behind this solution have a look at auto-fill and auto-fit: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

Comment: one question, how do I fix the height of the ul? I tried to fixed the height of the ul, but it is not working

Comment: @Rick I think you could use `height: 1fr;` on the `li` elements. This does not look very good when resizing but it should make the images remain in their original shape.

Comment: i mean I want set a height for ul, so that I can control the scrollbar. For example, I set 60px on ul, it just shows the first row of images, user need to scroll to view second row of images

Comment: I have edit the jsfiddle on the post. do you mind help me see whether it can achieve?

Comment: @Rick oh, I see. You would need to set the height on the "ul" element, for example height: 80px; and then force the overflow to be "scroll". This way the element should always be 80px high and a scrollbar appears.

Comment: yes!! exactly what I mean, it is possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }        
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(60px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
            grid-gap: 8px;
        }        
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
        }        
        img {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
        }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not know why the width of the li is absolute to 60px, but I think at smaller screen size the image should be little bigger. so below is the code. Hope it would help.

```css
ul {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin: calc(0.125em/2);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  transition: all 1.4s ease-in-out;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1600px) and (max-width:1920px) {
  li {
    min-width: calc((100%/12) - 0.125em);
    max-width: calc((100%/12) - 0.125em);
    min-height: calc((100%/12) - 0.125em);
    max-height: calc((100%/12) - 0.125em);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1280px) and (max-width:1599px) {
  li {
    min-width: calc((100%/10) - 0.125em);
    max-width: calc((100%/10) - 0.125em);
    min-height: calc((100%/10) - 0.125em);
    max-height: calc((100%/10) - 0.125em);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1279px) {
  li {
    min-width: calc((100%/8) - 0.125em);
    max-width: calc((100%/8) - 0.125em);
    min-height: calc((100%/8) - 0.125em);
    max-height: calc((100%/8) - 0.125em);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:1023px) {
  li {
    min-width: calc((100%/3) - 0.125em);
    max-width: calc((100%/3) - 0.125em);
    min-height: calc((100%/3) - 0.125em);
    max-height: calc((100%/3) - 0.125em);
  }
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```